# Flutter BLoC 8.0.0. not emiting new state properly

Tags: flutter, state, bloc

I have created a BLoC (8.0.0) in Flutter that handles events in the UI. I have a ToggleButtons widget where the user toggles between three buttons and whichever one is currently selected, returns a list of entities from the database which are then displayed on the screen. These are entities that have, among other parameters, the `bool isSale` and `bool isClosed`, and pressing each of the buttons should tell BLoC to search the database for entities with a different combination of these booleans, namely:

```
1 - isSale = true, isClosed = false
2 - isSale = true, isClosed = true 
3 - isSale = false, isClosed = false
```

I think the error must be somewhere in the code I'm going to post.

I have created states as follows:

```
abstract class DocViewerState extends Equatable {
  const DocViewerState();
}

class DocViewerLoadingState extends DocViewerState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class DocViewerLoadedState extends DocViewerState {
  bool isSale;
  bool isClosed;
  int? selectedIndex;

  DocViewerLoadedState({required this.isSale, required this.isClosed, required this.selectedIndex});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [isSale, isClosed];
}
```

The event I use to trigger this function looks like this:

```
abstract class DocViewerEvent extends Equatable {
  const DocViewerEvent();
}

class ModeChangedEvent extends DocViewerEvent {
  bool isSale;
  bool isClosed;

  ModeChangedEvent({required this.isSale, required this.isClosed});
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [isSale, isClosed];
}
```

I have set up an event handler to change the search mode, the function of which looks like this:

```
  void _onModeChanged(ModeChangedEvent event, Emitter<DocViewerState> emit) {
    emit(DocViewerLoadingState());
    this.isSale = event.isSale;
    this.isClosed = event.isClosed; // This is here because of the search stream outside of this function
    try {
      emit(DocViewerLoadedState(
        isClosed: event.isClosed,
        isSale: event.isSale,
        selectedIndex: null,
      )); // This emit works only for the first and third combination
    } catch (e) {
      print(e); /// I tried to put this here because I thought maybe there is some silent exception. 
                /// There is none.
    }
    print(event.isSale); // These are for printing the results, they are described below.
    print(event.isClosed);
    print(state);
  }
```

I double checked that I'm using Equatable for the states and event. I also tried setting up the try catch code that is above. These are results of prints below emitting:

1st combination (

```
I/flutter ( 5019): true
I/flutter ( 5019): false
I/flutter ( 5019): DocViewerLoadedState(true, false)
```

2nd combination

```
I/flutter ( 5019): true
I/flutter ( 5019): true
I/flutter ( 5019): DocViewerLoadingState()
```

3rd combination

```
I/flutter ( 5019): false
I/flutter ( 5019): false
I/flutter ( 5019): DocViewerLoadedState(false, false)
```

As you can see, the new state isn't updating although the parameters are passed correctly. What can I do to make it work as it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. For some reason, parameter *isClosed* seems to be some kind of keyword. Renaming *isClosed* to *closed* in all instances where it's used above suddenly made the emiting work.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a very wild guess, but it might be a race condition. Can you make the method `async` and add a delay before printing out the state?

Also, what I usually do is to use a Bloc Observer to monitor state changes:

```
class _DebugBlocObserver extends BlocObserver {
  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase<dynamic> bloc, Change<dynamic> change) {
    super.onChange(bloc, change);
    log('onChange(${bloc.runtimeType}, $change)');
  }

  @override
  void onError(BlocBase<dynamic> bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    log('onError(${bloc.runtimeType}, $error, $stackTrace)');
    super.onError(bloc, error, stackTrace);
  }
}
```

You can then register this observer when starting your app:

`Bloc.observer = _DebugBlocObserver();`

This prints out all state changes.

Here is the documentation: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttercountertutorial?id=blocobserver

Comment: I explained the problem wrong, the problem is that the state won't change *at all*, and the screen is therefore stuck in LoadingState, never switching to new state.